# cPanel - PostgreSQL Express React Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express, cpanel

I'm new to React Node/Express hosting.

Thank you in advance for taking a look.

Using a PERN stack - React.js, Node.js & Express with Postgresql. It works great on my local computer but not on the hosted server.  I can connect to the database from a terminal, display the node.js "It works!" message, and React simply fetches data from port 3001.
Steps Taken:

1. - I create a build for the react app (npm run build) and upload that content to  "/home/bidsvego/public_html/horserace/race/"
2. - I use Cpanel to create a Node application (public_html/horserace/nodeexpress/app.js) and get the default output  "It works!"
3. - I upload/overwrite with my own app.js, horsemodel.js, package.json files into the "/home/bidsvego/public_html/horserace/nodeexpress" folder.
4. - In Cpanel, I execute the "Run NPM Install" process.
5. - I also run the command at the top of the screen in a putty terminal:   -  "source /home/bidsvego/nodevenv/public_html/horserace/nodeexpress/10/bin/activate && cd /home/bidsvego/public_html/horserace/nodeexpress"
6. - My domainName/horserace/race game works, but there is NO Postgresql connection.  I "can" connect to the hosted database just from my local computer.  But not when the app is on the hosted server. The html page displays but no data is available.
7. - If I refresh the page the following is displayed:  Cannot GET /horserace/race/horse

The  app.js Code and horsemodel.js is below:
//==============================================================

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3001;

const horseModel = require("./horseModel");
app.use(express.json());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers"
  );
  next();
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  horseModel
    .getHorses()
    .then((response) => {
      res.status(200).send(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    });
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  horseModel
    .getJockeys()
    .then((response) => {
      res.status(200).send(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}, http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

// ======================================================================================
// horsemodel.js

```
const Pool = require("pg").Pool;
const pool = new Pool({
  user: "kevin",
  host: "localhost",
  database: "localhost",
  password: "XXXXXXXX",
  port: 5432,
});

const getHorses = () => {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    pool.query(
      `SELECT * 
      FROM horses 
   
};

module.exports = {
  getHorses,
.
.
etc.
  // createHorse,
  // deleteHorse,
};
```

Comment: Under `horsemodel.js`, you're connected to the localhost database. When the app is hosted on the server, the server cannot connect to your localhost.

Comment: @JeffreyRam not necessarily. When using cPanel there's usually a proxy server like nginx running over Node, and when you access localhost it's the server's localhost. The OP should carefully read the hosting provider's docs as it should provide details on how to connect to the database.

Comment: How do you know there connection failed? Did you read the logs? (Go inside the `www` directory, open `stderr.log`, then scroll to the bottom.)

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bidsvego/public_html/horserace/nodeexpress/app.js:30:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)

Comment: I ran this code from cPanel in a putty terminal:
source /home/bidsvego/nodevenv/public_html/horserace/nodeexpress/10/bin/activate && cd /home/bidsvego/public_html/horserace/nodeexpress

Comment: I changed the connection in horsemodle.js and reloaded.  No difference.
const Pool = require("pg").Pool;
const pool = new Pool({
  user: "bidsvego",
  host: "localhost",
  database: "bidsvego_race",
  password: "XXXXXXX",
  port: 5432,
});

Comment: I also ran"npm install express " to be sure it's installed.

Comment: Let us know if you found an answer. Struggling with the same